# For a React based form, would it be acceptable to have a text input element as a React Component?

Tags: reactjs, forms

I have a SPA application that comprises of a single React-based form. Therein, I need to include quite a few input elements to the form. I was wondering whether it would be acceptable for the individual text input elements to be turned into a separate React component that I can reuse for the form component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's absolutely nothing wrong with it. Material UI for instance has an input component.